# English "would" and conditional in Japanese

Tags: conditionals

So I'm familiar with many of the conditional forms in Japanese, と and なら and たら being common ones, but as I understand these only work in sentences with clauses and function in the role of English's "if" and sometimes "when". However in English we also have would which we use as a conditional. It's often used like "If X, Y would/n't". But we also use would on its own with the the if clause dropped. And I haven't come across an equivalent in Japanese and was wondering if their was a way to put that conditional would in the second part and drop the first if part?

Some example sentences in English:

"I'd go." (If i had money; if I was in your shoes; if I could, being implied.)

"It would not have happened."

Comment: You can end sentences with たら/なら like ああ金があったら(なあ). But it is like using if clause alone.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Let's see if [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95572/about-conditional-sentences-in-japanese) gets your answer too :).